# Validate() returns false but it has been saved in the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spock

I am starting to use grails and I have stumble into a behaviour that I don't understand.

Given this domain class

```
class Team {

    String name
    Date since
    Date until

    static hasMany = [teamMembers:Player]

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
        until nullable: true
        until(validator: { val, obj ->
            val?.after(obj.since)
        })

        teamMembers maxSize: 8
        //teamMembers size: 0..8
    }
}
```

I wanted to have an integration test that checks that you can't actually have more than 8 players in one team so I wrote a simplified version of this:

```
void "The team can only have up to 8 players"(){

    given:
    Player[] players = (1..9).collect {new Player(name: "Foo")}

    Team t = new Team(name:"Bar", since: new Date())

    expect:
    players.each {it.validate()}
    t.validate()

    when:

    players.each {it.save()}
    t.save()

    players.each {t.addToTeamMembers(it)}

    then:
    t.validate() == false
    t.getTeamMembers().size() == 9
    Team.get(t.id).teamMembers.size == 9
    Team.first().teamMembers.size == 9
    Team.findAll()[0].teamMembers.size == 9
    Team.findByName("Bar").teamMembers.size == 9
}
```

As far as I know, *get*, *find* *, etc hit the database. So why does my team fail to validate (expected behaviour) but it has 9 players in the database?
What am I missing?

Notes: Name is not PK for players and I have tested with both constraints, size and maxSize.

Comment: employees.each ? do you mean players.each?

Comment: Is this a unit or integration test?

Comment: @codehx yes, players.each

Comment: So my answer doesnt help you?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith integration test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to this problem, [I have found this answer from Peter Ledbrook](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-doesn-t-perform-validate-when-addTo-td1356815.html):

As a summary for this link:

> ... as soon as you call "save()" on the Team object, it 
>   is attached to the session. Any subsequent changes to that object will
>   then be persisted to the database *including any player you add*

If that is right (I haven't really tried), that should fix it:

```
void "The team can only have up to 8 players"(){

given:
   Player[] players = (1..9).collect {new Player(name: "Foo")}

   Team t = new Team(name:"Bar", since: new Date())

expect:
   players.each {it.validate()}
   t.validate()

when:
   players.each {t.addToTeamMembers(it)}
   t.save()      

then:
   !t.validate()
}
```

which means that should only save once the team object (supposing Player has a belongsTo to the Team domain class). Let me know if that works.

Comment: That's it, although it has help me could you edit your answer so it contains at least a brief summary of the answer in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bug?  `employees.each {t.addToTeamMembers(it)}`?
Because you dont have `employees` variable.

Assuming you want to say `players.each {t.addToTeamMembers(it)}`:

I think you need to say t.save() after   `players.each {t.addToTeamMembers(it)}` if you want to test to persist.

Your test is not failing because your team size is 9 but you  are not actually saving the team.

**So try saving before your `when`**

Comment: Adding t.save() after t.addToTeamMembers() renders the same result.

Comment: how about t.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)?

Comment: flush: true doesn't change the outcome, failOnError obviously makes the test to fail.
My question is more towards, if get, find and all of those methods are hitting or not the database, and if not, why?